# HTML text in a Database

Tags: php, html, sql

I want, that a user can format text (**just *like* in *this* box**) - And should store it in a database.

How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: You might look at some web-based wysiwyg editors like TinyMCE and then you can store the html code in the database. There are also some nice markdown editors out there as well. Here is an example codepen of an embedded tinymce editor: https://codepen.io/josdea/pen/dXYdpd

Comment: This seems to be a question on application architecture which would be ill-suited for this site. If you have code / a data model that you have difficulties with, please show it along with expected and actual behavior as well as error messages.

Comment: stackoverflow is not code factory.Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the string containing the HTML code of the text in the database. 
Usually a string like this: 
'**String** *test* format' 
is saved in the database as 
'`<b>String</b> <i>test</i> format`'.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for every information i got.**

Due to you i started looking for wysiwyg ediots. (Like TinyMCE <- but i didnt used that^^)

Im using CKEdior - thanks!